# Woocommerce REST API - add filter to set maximum query per page for product brands

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api, api

I'm trying to list all my product brands in a single page, currently i'm able to get only 100 brands per page by using `wp-json/wc/v3/products/brands?per_page=100.` but if i set per_page=200, i'm getting status 400 with the following error

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): per_page","data":{"status":400,"params":{"per_page":"per_page must be between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive)"}}}
```

is there any way i can set a maximum limit to 200 in the functions.php. I checked the documentation, i couldn't find anything that is useful.

Please note that i already set the maximum query limit for products like this in the functions.php

```
add_filter('rest_product_collection_params', 'maximum_api_filter');
function maximum_api_filter($query_params) {
    $query_params['per_page']["maximum"]=300;
    return $query_params;
}
```

is there a similar way to achieve this for brands also ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no brand fields in WooCommerce core by default. [This answer](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/missing-brand-field/) comes from a post 2 years ago, given by an engineer from Automattic. I double-checked the validity of this answer again today.

Yes correct use vendor_id or another field which is valid. Let me share mine which was worked for me.

i place exactly same code in function.php file.

> add_filter('rest_product_collection_params', 'maximum_api_filter');
> function maximum_api_filter($query_params) {
> $query_params['per_page']["maximum"]=300;
> return $query_params;
> }

but my filter was like-

> wp-json/wc/v3/products?status=publish&vendor_id=13&lang=en&per_page=300&